# Generator inifinitesimal SU(3)

Tags: lie-groups

I have to compute generator $SU(3)$ and I got 6 generator with diagonal = 0. I check in wiki, it says $SU(3)$ have 8. From where 2 generators else?

Comment: If you showed me your six generators, I'm sure I could write down two more....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The remaining two generators have non-zero diagonal.

Comment: sorry there is a mistake in my calculation and I have 8 generators now thanks

Comment: Delete the question, then.